# How to calculate the magnetic flux through a circular area

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

A constant magnetic field passes through a circular area (of a solenoid). I'm trying to calculate the flux using

$$\phi_B= \int B dA$$

$B=0.2$ Tesla, Diameter of the solenoid (and therefore circle) $= 10 cm$

I convert $dA$ to $r dr d\theta$ and do the integral and I get about $0.003$ but the solution to the problem says $0.785$

What am I doing wrong??

...here's the question as it is:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. Please note, that this is not a homework help site. Please consider to read [our policy on how to ask homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1):

Since the magnetic field is constant, the flux through a single turn is $\phi_B = B \int dA = BA = B \pi d^2 / 4$, where $d$ is the diameter. The total flux is $N \phi_B$, where $N$ is the number of turns.

If you want to do the area integral explicitly:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int dA &=& \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{d/2} dr \ r \\
&=& 2 \pi \left[\frac{r^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{d/2} \\
&=& \frac{\pi d^2}{4} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$